# Java- How to compare 1D array with 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have trouble compare 1D array with 2D array. I already import the txt file to 1D array and 2D array. The 1D array contains 20 correct answer (True and False). The 2D array contains 2000 student answers (100 students * 20 answers per student).

I want to design a program that shows the score for each student, which I already tried to program. Can you help me to figure out which part I did wrong?

The second part of the program is to print out for each question, how many student got right for each question?

Thank you so much!!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Scores
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
    File AnswerFile = new File("/Users/shaovera/NetBeansProjects/Scores/QuestionAnswer.txt");
    FileReader AnswerReader = new FileReader(AnswerFile);
    BufferedReader answerreader = new BufferedReader(AnswerReader);

    String[] words = new String[20];
    for(int a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
      words[a] = answerreader.readLine();
      System.out.println(words[a]);
    }
    answerreader.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
    File StudentFile = new File("/Users/shaovera/NetBeansProjects/Scores/StudentAnswer.txt");
    FileReader StudentReader = new FileReader(StudentFile);
    BufferedReader studentreader = new BufferedReader(StudentReader);

    String[][] table = new String[100][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
        table[i][j] = studentreader.readLine();
        System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");

      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
    studentreader.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  int count=0;
  int student=0;    
  String[] words = new String[20];
  String[][] table = new String[100][20];
  for (int column = 0; column < words.length; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
      if (words[row] == table[row][column]) {
        count++; 
        student++;
        System.out.print("student#" + student + ":" + count);
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help us by stating exacly what's the problem with your code. Do you have errors, stacktrace, not expected behavior ?

Comment: Your `String[] words` and `String[][] table` are empty. You read in the data into local try/catch blocks, then allocate new arrays which have nothing in them. You're also using `==` to compare Strings, but you should be using `.equals()` instead.

Comment: Yes, my problem is I can not print out the score of each student.  The code I think I did wrong is start from   int count = 0;  (The very bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this correct code (I wrote comment in line when you have problems)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[]words= new String[20]; // before load from file
    String[][]table =new String[100][20]; // before load from file

try{
    File AnswerFile=new File("/Users/shaovera/NetBeansProjects/Scores/QuestionAnswer.txt");
    FileReader AnswerReader = new FileReader(AnswerFile);
    BufferedReader answerreader = new BufferedReader(AnswerReader);


    for(int a=0; a<words.length;a++){
        words[a]=answerreader.readLine();
        System.out.println(words[a]);
    }
    answerreader.close();
}
catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

try{
    File StudentFile=new File("/Users/shaovera/NetBeansProjects/Scores/StudentAnswer.txt");
    FileReader StudentReader = new FileReader(StudentFile);
    BufferedReader studentreader = new BufferedReader(StudentReader);           

    for (int i = 0; i <table.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j < table[i].length; j++){
            table[i][j]= studentreader.readLine();
            System.out.print(table[i][j]+" ");

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    studentreader.close();
}

catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

    for (int column = 0; column < words.length; column++) {
        int student = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {                            
            if (Objects.equals(words[column],table[row][column])) {
                student++;
            }
        }            
        System.out.println("student#" + student + ":" + column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. But why use Objects.equals() over `words[row].equals(table[row][column])` ?

Comment: In fact it's Idea autorefactoring (because words[row] could be null in general case and words[row].equals throw NullPointerException)

Comment: Thank you for your help!!  But it is not working.  The result said:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
 at Scores.main(Scores.java:54)

Comment: I fixed code, how it's must work, you use words[rows] but need words[column]

Comment: Hi Viacheslav. It is working now.  But the result is not what I looking for.  It just print out count value from 1 to 1000.  What I want is to compare the correct answer( inside words array, 20 values), with each students' response( inside table array, each row has 20 values, 100 rows). The result will print out the score for each student.    Do I write the wrong for loop or wrong IF statement?   Hope you can understand what I talk about.

Comment: Yes, I figure it. Thank you so much!!